# Merge files based on matching of first column

Tags: awk, join, merge

I have two files:
File1

```
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044 0.9626 688423261 2 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044 0.9626 688423263 2 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
```

File2:

```
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 1 29303546
```

Desired output

```
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 1 29303546
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 1 29303546
```

So file 1 has many more rows than file 2. I only want to keep rows in the output that are in file 2 based on column1.

I have tried join but I cant get it to work right-it will tell me my files are not sorted

```
join -j 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.2,2.3 <(sort -k1 file1) <(sort -k1 file2)
```

Preferably I would prefer an awk command. File 1 will be very large.
I have tried

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1 > output
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Sorry I cant comment below but just to clarify file not all rows in column1 in file 1 will be in file2.

The awk command

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next} $1 in a {print $0, a[$1]}'
```

will only keep the amount of rows there is in file 2. But ideally what I want is were for expample ARS-BFGL-10975 is repeated twice (realistically way more) to appear twice in my output.

Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the examples you show. Every single 1st column in file1 is also present in file2.

Comment: glenn’s answer works for me (i.e., for your example data, it produces the six lines of output that you say you want). I notice that, when you quote it (when you say it doesn’t work), you quote it incompletely.  Are you maybe passing the file arguments as `file1 file2` rather than `file2 file1`, as is required for it to work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Using your example data:

```
$ join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 1 29303546
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 1 29303546
```

This *appears* to do what you would want it to do, apart from the ordering of the lines in the output (which is sorted here, and I don't know if that's significant to you or not).

The default join field is the first field, so `-j 1` is not needed (this is a GNU `join` extension).

The default output of `join`: "Each
     output line consists of the join field, the remaining fields from file1
     and then the remaining fields from file2" (from [the OpenBSD manual](http://man.openbsd.org/join)). This means that the output field specification that you used isn't needed either as it matches the default behaviour.

For `sort`, `-k1` is likewise equivalent to the default.

I don't know what caused the error message that you got other than accidentally using `sort -c`.

Comment: Can this shorthand `<(sort file1)` be used in bash script?

Comment: @ruruskyi That's a process substitution. It can most definitely be used in a `bash` script.

Answer (score 1):

For your awk command, you're only missing the check to see if the key from file1 has been seen in file2

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next} $1 in a {print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1 > output
# ................................^^^^^^^
```